# WCF not accessible in Azure

Tags: wcf, azure

I have a WCF service hosted in a webrole in Azure.

When I test it in dev fabric it works ok from my web page (other web role).

But when I deploy it in the Cloud it doesn't seems to be running, although the webrole is ready.

When I use Fiddler to do a GET on one of the public methods of my WCF service, I get:

> [Fiddler] Connection to
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudapp.net failed.
>   Exception Text: A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did
>   not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to
>   respond yyyyyyyyyyyyyy

This is the service configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="GovGuard" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
  <WebRole name="GovGuard.Services">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="GuardServiceEndpointBinding" endpointName="GuardServiceEndpoint" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="DevelopmentConnectionString" />
      <Setting name="GovGuardStorageConnectionString" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="GuardServiceEndpoint" protocol="http" port="81" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
    </Imports>
    <LocalResources>
      <LocalStorage name="MyCompany.GovGuard.Services.svclog" sizeInMB="1000" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" />
    </LocalResources>
  </WebRole>
  <WebRole name="GovGuard.Web">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="Web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="GuardWebEndpointBinding" endpointName="GuardWebEndpoint" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="GuardServiceUrl" />
      <Setting name="DevelopmentConnectionString" />
      <Setting name="GovGuardStorageConnectionString" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="GuardWebEndpoint" protocol="http" port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Imports>
      <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
    </Imports>
    <LocalResources>
      <LocalStorage name="MyCompany.GovGuard.Web.svclog" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" sizeInMB="1000" />
    </LocalResources>
  </WebRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

(edit)
In my investigation of the problem it may be this: I use the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types assembly as file reference in the WCF project. I use copy-local = true to copy the assembly to the bin folder and it is packaged in the .csx file. But.... the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types also needs the SqlServerSpatial.dll library (not assembly). I created a postbuild script to copy that dll to the bin also, but I didn't succeed....

Maybe someone can help me how to package a dll (not an assembly) to the .csx file....

(edit) 
Found it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg271395

Comment: You might have to share some code... a common mistake is having the port set to something other than 80.  Might want to check your ServiceDefinition.csdef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the solution that works: I develop on a 32 bit Win7 machine and I copied the SqlServerSpatial.dll from my machine to the WCF project (with Copy to Output Directory and BuildAction Content). That caused a weird error message in the Cloud, because that library was 32 bit! I renewed the library with a 64 bit version and now after deploy in the Cloud everything works!

Answer (score 1):

WCF does not play nicely if you are trying to do a self hosted service.

Because of the way that the HTTP.sys registration happens it does it on the local machine name and does not allow you to do a wildcard registration accepting the load balanced name. The option you have is to use a internal endpoint and try to connect from your web host the IP of the worker role.

What I ended up doing was just converting my WCF service to a MVC endpoint and making my worker role be a web application. It's not the most elegant, but it worked.

Comment: Hi Aaron. My solution works. WCF shouldn't be a problem in Azure, but watch out for using CLR libraries that are using native libraries... In my case the whole WCF service wasn't running because I didn't include the native library as part of the Azure package!

Comment: That's awesome.. my issues is probably more deeply rooted in my love/hate relationship with WCF than anything.